# How to keep lowercase 'i' as a single word in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook on XP keeps changing the sentence

```
'..has two lowercase 'i's to 

'...has two lowercase 'I's.
```

How can I get Outlook to leave my 'i's alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you type the i press ctrl+z when it uppercases it.