# Stop online Office apps from replacing lowercase single-letter word "i" with "I"

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, spell-check, autocorrect

### What happens?

In Scandinavian languages such as Norwegian, just the letter "i" as a word means "in" or "inside". When I type this word into an online Office app, it gets replaced with the uppercase English word "I".

---

### What I am *not* asking

This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/431155/how-to-keep-lowercase-i-as-a-single-word-in-outlook), as that question/answer pair addresses how to undo the replacement *once it has already happened*. I also *do not* want to change the document's language settings to Norwegian, because:

- Many of the documents I write are mixed-language, often comprising as many as three languages.
- These settings have to be set on every document.

  - Even if the default setting can be changed, I'll still have problems because of the previous (top-level) bullet point
- If a (OneNote Notebook) document already has text in it, changing the language settings for the entire file at once seems impossible; one can only change the settings for the selected text.

  - Further, when I set these settings on a document that already exists, the language setting resets to English (US) every time I move my cursor into an empty position, for instance the start of a new line.
- I am my own spell checker. Mistakes are rarely made and almost invariably caught immediately. I am sure other proficient typists will also recognize the "feeling" of having typed a word incorrectly.

---

### So what am I asking?

I am asking instead how to *prevent it from ever happening in the first place*. I have been able to do this for offline Office apps, but I can't find the same setting in the online apps. Another acceptable solution is disabling all spell checking completely, cf. the last bullet point in the above list.

---

Note that going to Home > Spelling > Set Proofing Language and checking "Don't check spelling" usually doesn't do anything at all; next time I open Set Proofing Language, the checkbox is once again *unchecked*, and even on the rare occasion that the checkbox stays checked, the replacement **still happens**.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the solution you are looking for, but I run into the same problems, and what I do is uncheck everything except the 1st box in

```
Home > Spelling > AutoCorrect Options
```

(cf. [Desired AutoCorrect Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCPHT.jpg)). The problem with this solution is that the configuration is not persisted across sessions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, please refer to the final paragraph of my question: The settings under `Home > Spelling` _reset_ every time I close the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

We generally request that question-askers say what they’ve tried. 
So this may be something you’ve tried and ruled out,
but I don’t know, because you haven’t specified.

I don’t know about the online version,
but, in an installed copy of Microsoft Word,

- Click on “File”,
- Click on “Options”,
- Click on “Proofing”,
- Click the “AutoCorrect Options” button,

  [image: Word Options]
- (On the “AutoCorrect” tab) type “i” in the Replace box. 
  «Replace “i” with “I”» will scroll into view:

  [image: AutoCorrect Options]
- Click “Delete”.
- And, of course, click “OK”.

If this doesn’t work, you may need to go back and uncheck “Automatically use suggestions from the spelling checker”.

(These instructions are based on Microsoft Word 2013.)

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, whether I have tried it or not is a moot point, since the question is very specifically about online apps. I also believe that I _am_ stating what I have tried, in mentioning that `Home -> Spelling -> Set Proofing Language...` does nothing, and that I **have** found a way to do this in offline Office apps; other than that, "what I've tried" consists solely of looking for the setting and not finding it, which is also specified in the question. However, I suggest you leave your answer as it may help people experiencing this problem in the offline Office apps.